# bi-directionally sync Google Photos on external drive

Tags: photos, google, google-apps

I see in this post ([Any way to auto download or sync all Google+ photos to my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177816/any-way-to-auto-download-or-sync-all-google-photos-to-my-mac)) that there's a good solution to bi-directionally syncing photos between my laptop and my Google Photos account (which would also sync photos uploaded from my phone, which occurs automatically).  B/c this storage can potentially become a bit large, I'd like to store my Google Photos on a 256GB SDHC card that is always plugged in to my computer.  The problem is, it appears I need the Google Photos folder to reside within my Google Drive folder, which is not on this external storage.

Is there a good way to point my local Google Photos folder to external storage without messing up my other Google Drive folders?

Answer (score 1):

1. Move Google drives folder to the new drive
2. In Google Drive's settings, you should be able to select another directory.

I'm not completely sure if this works, as I've only done it this way:

1. Sign out of drive
2. Resign-in, and during the setup process, select advanced, and choose the folder location